# How to define global load balancer in ingress.yaml instead of defaulting to classic load balancer - gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl

We have an ingress.yaml, which we kubectl apply to our GKE cluster in order to setup all of the load balancing components, however, we are wanting to have the global http(s) load balancer instead of the http(s) classic one but I can't see what annotations to use.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: project-stage
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: project-ip
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: lb-http-to-https
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: project-service
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: url
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: project-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[Ingress for External HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress-xlb) deploys the [global external HTTP(S) load balancer (classic)](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https). This internet-facing load balancer is deployed globally across Google's edge network as a managed and scalable pool of load balancing resources.

Instead of that you can identify the mode which is suited for you by using this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#identifying_the_mode)(delete the previous load balancer)

You can [create an external http(s) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress#multiple_backend_services) after selecting mode so that you can  specify that the load balancer will be the default global http(s) load balancer.